# Row Compression in AlwaysOn Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, compression

I want to implement row compression on some databases that are in an availability group. Are row and page compression supported in availability group databases? 
 Does it affect the replication, failover, configuration, or structure in any way? Does the role and mode of the node make a difference?

Comment: In the same way that index rebuilds would affect (or rather be affected by) the AG role.  Synchronous commit mode will cause the primary to go slower, but the secondary would never fall behind.  Asynchronous commit mode could result in the secondary falling behind, perhaps significantly so.  It would depend on how large a table you were compressing.  I would schedule it for off-peak hours.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanFite. Now that part is clear, but my question was actually about the time when the initial compression is already implemented. Will it hinder the work of AG? So basically it works fine with both modes, right?

Comment: It will not hinder the functioning of an AG.  The AG just sends modified pages to it's partner nodes to process (save to disk).  It doesn't matter whether they are compressed or un-compressed.  Depending on workload, compression may help here as it may help in other aspects of SQL.  It's not just for saving on storage, you can see performance benefits as well.

Comment: @JonathanFite You should post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compression is not listed as a restriction in the documentation at [Prerequisites, Restrictions, and Recommendations for Always On availability groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/prereqs-restrictions-recommendations-always-on-availability), so that is the official reference that indicates it is supported with availability groups.  There are no special considerations for configuration, and it does not matter whether synchronous or asynchronous replication is used.

Row and page level compression will have no direct impact on availability groups as far as functionality is concerned, but there will be a small increase in CPU utilization on the primary server to compress the data when written, and uncompress when read, so it's possible that extra resource usage could impact availability group replication as it also requires CPU.  In general, though, if your system has adequate CPU this will be of no concern.  Additionally, if the secondary is used for reading, additional CPU will be used to uncompress the data.  Again, the CPU required to do this is quite minimal and will only be of concern if there are other factors causing the CPU utilization to be excessively high.

The replication process is simply copying transactions from the transaction log to the secondary servers (to oversimplify it a bit), so it really doesn't know or care about what data is actually in that transaction.  When the log record gets to the secondary, it is placed in the transaction log there and committed to the database just as if the transaction had originated locally.

If the replication process had to understand the contents of every transaction that is replicated, whether the data is compressed, encrypted, or whatever, it would be far slower.